# How to min function without group by in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Consider the following hive query.

```
SELECT  
    id,
    name,
    min(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss')) as SYSDATE
  FROM tablename
```

The reason why I used `min` function is that I wanted the same `SYSDATE` in all of my records. If I don't add `min` here, multiple `SYSDATE` may appear.

I got an error running the query:

```
An exception was caught.
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 3:4 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'name'
```

So I added `GROUP BY` in my query and it worked.

```
SELECT  
    id,
    name,
    min(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss')) as SYSDATE
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id, name
```

But what if I have twenty or more columns? Isn't it inconvenient to add them all to `GROUP BY`? And why should I add `GROUP BY` here? I just want a consistent `SYSDATE` all across the records. Is there any other way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have any concern about performance, try to use window function to calculate `min`:

```
SELECT  
    id ,
    name ,
    min(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss')) over(partition by 1) as SYSDATE
FROM tablename
```